# How do I deal with a NoReverseMatch error?

Tags: django, django-templates

Its my first time coming across such an error and i have looked around but failed to find the error happening in the same situation.The redirection is supposed to happen to happen when a user submits a form.

In my views i use a reverse() function to return a *url* and redirect to it.
Here are is the views:

```
def get_category(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all().prefetch_related('item')
    form = ItemAddToCartForm(request=request, label_suffix=':')
    # need to evaluate the HTTP method
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # add to order..create the bound form
        postdata = request.POST.copy()
        form = ItemAddToCartForm(request,postdata)
        # check validation of posted data
        if form.is_valid():
            # add to order and redirect to order page
            order.add_to_order(request)
            # if test cookie worked, get rid of it
            if request.session.test_cookie_worked():
                request.session.delete_test_cookie()
            url =urlresolvers.reverse('show_order')
            # redirect to order page
            return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
    else:
        # it's a GET, create the unbound from. Note request as a Kwarg
        form = ItemAddToCartForm(request=request,label_suffix=':')
    # assign the hidden input the item slug
    # set the test cookie on our first GET request
    request.session.set_test_cookie()
    context={
        'categories':categories,
        'form':form,
#       'menu':menu,

    }
    return render_to_response('category.html',context,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is the view of the *url* it directs to:

```
def show_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Remove':
            order.remove_from_order(request)
        if postdata['submit'] == 'Update':
            order.update_order(request)
    order_items = order.get_order_items(request)
    page_title  = 'F4L order' 
    order_subtotal = order.order_subtotal(request)
    return render_to_response('public/order.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the *urls* for the above view:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'live.views',
    url(r'^$', view="show_order",name="order_index"),
)
```

urls for both views:

```
url(r'^orders/', include('live.urls')),
url(r'^menu/$','live.views.get_category'),
```

here is the form html:

```
<form method="post" action=".">
  <a href="{% url order_index %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
  <br />
   <input type="submit" value="Add To Order" name="submit">
  </a>

Traceback:
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/f4l/live/views.py" in get_category
  39.           url =urlresolvers.reverse('show_order')
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  476.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  396.                 "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /menu/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'show_order' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value passed to reverse should be the name of the url not the view.

```
url =urlresolvers.reverse('order_index')
```

Comment: thanks charl, but then another problem pops up with the html, like any button i press (be it filling in the form) redirects the page. Have you come across this.

Comment: any button in a form which has it type set to submit (type="submit") would submit the form. Not sure if I understood this correctly.

Comment: No worries charl, i jus fixed, it was my html. I had put the the redirect url `<a href="{% url order_index %}">` in the wrong place.